# CompositeNavigationProp, 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ a: ParamListBase; b: string; c: {}; }'

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

In my ReactNative application, I have defined a stack-drawer composition like below

```typescript
const Auth = createStackNavigator<AuthStackParamList>();
const Main = createStackNavigator<MainStackParamList>();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator<DrawerParamList>();

const AuthStack = () => (
  <Auth.Navigator initialRouteName="LoginScreen">
    <Auth.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
    <Auth.Screen name="SignUpScreen" component={SignUpScreen} />
  </Auth.Navigator>
);
// In order to have access to "openDrawer()"  I had to make a composite type (types.ts)
const MainStack = ({navigation}: {navigation: MainNavigationProps}) => (
  <Main.Navigator  initialRouteName="DashboardScreen">
    <Main.Screen
      name="ProfileScreen"
      component={ProfileScreen}
      options={{
        headerLeft: () => <IconButton onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} />
      }}
    />
    <Main.Screen
      name="DashboardScreen"
      component={DashboardScreen}
      options={{
        headerLeft: () => <IconButton onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} />
      }}
    />
    <Main.Screen
      name="SettingScreen"
      component={SettingScreen}
      options={{
        headerLeft: () => <IconButton onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} />
      }}
    />
  </Main.Navigator>
);

// And this component (Navigation.tsx) returns 
 <NavigationContainer >
      {isAuthenticated ? (
        <Drawer.Navigator
          initialRouteName="MainStack"
          drawerContent={(prop) => <DrawerComponent {...prop} />}>
          <Drawer.Screen name="MainStack" component={MainStack} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      ) : (
        <AuthStack />
      )}
 </NavigationContainer>
```

And in the `types.ts` have defined types like

```typescript
import {CompositeNavigationProp} from '@react-navigation/core';
import {DrawerNavigationProp} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import {StackNavigationProp} from '@react-navigation/stack';

export type AuthStackParamList = {
  LoginScreen: undefined;
  SignUpScreen: undefined;
};

export type MainStackParamList = {
  ProfileScreen: undefined;
  DashboardScreen: undefined;
  SettingScreen: {id: number};
};

export type DrawerParamList = {
  MainStack: MainStackParamList;
};

export type MainNavigationProps = CompositeNavigationProp<
  StackNavigationProp<MainStackParamList>, // <---- The type error in this line
  DrawerNavigationProp<DrawerParamList>
>;
```

But I get the type error in the mentioned line as;

```typescript
 Type 'StackNavigationProp<MainStackParamList, string>' does not
 satisfy the constraint 'NavigationProp<ParamListBase, string, any,
 any, {}>'.   Type 'StackNavigationProp<MainStackParamList, string>' is
 not assignable to type 'PrivateValueStore<ParamListBase, string, {}>'.
     Types of property '''' are incompatible.
       Type '({ a: MainStackParamList; b: keyof MainStackParamList; c: {}; } & { a: MainStackParamList; b: string; c:
 StackNavigationEventMap; }) | undefined' is not assignable to type '{
 a: ParamListBase; b: string; c: {}; }'.
         Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ a: ParamListBase; b: string; c: {}; }'.ts(2344)
```

Are these the correct construction when you have a stack as the direct child of a drawer, and the way to define types for them? If so how should I get rid of the error? I could not undrestand the source fo the error.

Answer (score 1):

Please give a initialParame to the Setting Screen something like this.

```
<Main.Screen
  name="SettingScreen"
  component={SettingScreen}
  initialParams={{ id: user.id }}
  options={{
    headerLeft: () => <IconButton onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} />
  }}
/>
```

Please put attention here on your code.
https://prnt.sc/1lkdhss
id must be number in type

Comment: Thanks, for some reason the updated ESLint does not throw that error anymore, but a great hint. I never thought of initial params, nice.